# Hover over an element that will take effect in another

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
.tratoresList h3{
    font-family: "opensans-light-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #000;
    width: 210px;
    text-align: center;
}
.tratoresList strong{
    font-family: "opensans-extrabold-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #000;
    width: 210px;
}
.tratoresList strong, .tratoresList h3:hover{
    font-family: "opensans-extrabold-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #a80000;
    width: 210px;
}
```

And here is the HTML, can someone say me what is wrong?

```
<ul class="margin-top-50 tratoresList">
<li>
    <img src="./imagens/trator1.png" />
        <h3>linha <strong>4000</strong></h3>

    <div class="tratoresListArrow"></div>
</li>
```

When I hover within the `h3` he has to do the hover also in `strong` and vice versa.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: this is not allowed - maybe in a future release of css, just maybe, actually if they are siblings or parent / child  -  YES , PLEASE POST HTML

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: Why <strong> inside the <h3> ?

Comment: because the `h3` may receive a strong text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.tratoresList h3{
    font-family: "opensans-light-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #000;
    width: 210px;
    text-align: center;
}
.tratoresList strong{
    font-family: "opensans-extrabold-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #000;
    width: 210px;
}
.tratoresList h3:hover, .tratoresList h3:hover ~ strong{
    font-family: "opensans-extrabold-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #a80000;
    width: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tratoresList">
  <h3>CSS - HOVER AN ELEMENT THAT WILL TAKE EFFECT IN ANOTHER</h3>
  <strong>I THINK ITS POSSIBLE NOW !</strong>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you....

Comment: Its very complex. i think. may be its not possible.
But, removing the strong tag and doing simply solves the problem easily.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in CSS3 unless the `strong` element can be specified in the same selector as `h3:hover` (right now, this only works when the `strong` element is an  sibling), however otherwise you cannot do "disjoint" effects using pure CSS, you must use scripting. Here's a quick example (that doesn't use jQuery for once). I haven't tested it - it might work, it might not. Have fun!

```
document.querySelectorAll(".tratoresList h3")forEach( function(el1) {
    el1.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {

        document.querySelectorAll(".tratoresList strong").forEach( function(el2) { 
            el2.classList.toggleClass("hoverEffect");
        } );
    });
} );
```

Comment: you're going to scare people with jQuery-less javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the style of text in strong tags(inside h3) when you hover over h3..

```
.tratoresList h3:hover strong{
    color: green;
}}
```